# How to find how many times a number occurs in a list without using any in-built functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find how many times a number occurs in a list without using any in-built functions. The below code won't work:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
for i in a:
    c = 0
    if a[i] == a[i]+1:
        c =+1
        print(c)
```

Comment: Look into a `dict`, you can keep track of the numbers you have seen and how many of them you have seen. This has an easy answer but I think this is a good learning problem.

Comment: what are the range of numbers that you have in the list. min max?

Comment: `for i in a` returns the item value, not the item list index.

Comment: `if a[i] == a[i]+1` cannot ever be true...

Comment: @NikosM.: No, it won't (see John Gordon's comments.)

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 2):

Num is the number you are looking for. Not sure if that is what you are want.

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
c = 0 
num = 1;
for i in a:
    if i == num:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Or this

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
b = []
t = 0
x = 0 
while t < len(a):
  c = 0
  temp = a
  for i in temp:
    if i == x:
      c += 1
  b.append(c)
  t += c
  x += 1
print(b)
```

outputs [0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1]

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to see 3 answers with no use of a dictionary to solve this problem.

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
counts = {}
for x in l:
    if x in counts:
        counts[x] += 1
    else:
        counts[x] = 1
```

After running the above code, counts stores the number of occurrences of each item in list l with the items themselves (numbers, in this case) as keys.

```
>>> l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> counts = {}
>>> for x in l:
...     if x in counts:
...         counts[x] += 1
...     else:
...         counts[x] = 1
...
>>> counts
{1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly this is easy if you know the `max`. I assumed your `min=0` and `max=5` (you can change)

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
freq=[0]*6 # assume 5 is your max
for i in a:
    freq[i] += 1

print(freq)
print(freq[num])
```

#### DEFAULTDICT

if you dont know the `max`

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
d=defaultdict(int)
for i in a:
    d[i] +=1
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

An ugly but almost fun way I have seen this done is to loop through your list, find the maximum, create a list of that size, and then reloop through and increment the index in your new list as you hit your values.

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5]

max = -1
for i in a:
    if i > max:
        max = i

long_list = [0] * (max + 1) #create the list of the max size

for i in a:
    long_list[i] = long_list[i] + 1

print(long_list)
```

output here is: [0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]

Again this is not space efficient at all but I enjoy the implementation as I think it is fun.

The issue with this implementation is if you have a list such as [1,2,3,545543,34]. Then your output will be a little wild printed that way and a lot of space is wasted.